# Popup Menu with Sub item

Tags: android

I want to display popup menu with sub items as shown in the image.

[image]

What is the correct approach for this.

Comment: I want to do this dynamically as the data keeps changing. I am able to display the Menu items with checkbox but not sub items as shown above.

Comment: how do you `display the Menu items with checkbox `?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko 
`popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, menu_icon, Gravity.LEFT)
popupMenu.menu.add("social").setCheckable(true)`

Comment: You could use `popupMenu.menu.addSubMenu()`, but the problem here is that it does not support icons and is not checkable. Likely you will have to create your own view and show it with `PopupWindow`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have already tried `popupMenu.menu.addSubMenu()`. Well, I will try the custom view with `PopupWindow`. Thank you.